# 5-second count down timer

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I have a simple question. I'm trying to add a a count down timer to my first ever project. I'm planning on putting the timer on the top of the page, and I want it to display the current time left starting from 5:00 to 0:00. I know how to do it using `setInterval` which could do something like `time--` every second, but I want it to also display the current milliseconds and I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Any help would be very much appreciated!

This is the code I've written so far, and right now it just has a 5 second timeout used in the assignWords() method.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  // Dictionary object used to manipulate anagrams
  var dictionary = {};

  // List of letters used to help create incorrect choices
  dictionary.letters = [
  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
  'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
  'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
  's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
  'y', 'z'];

  // List of words that are used for anagram questions
  dictionary.words = [
  'adaxial', 'agreeably', 'antinoise', 'asthenia', 'astint', 'babushka', 'bailiffry', 'bathtub', 'bestab', 'bestiary', 'bibulous', 'bordage', 'bostonite', 'brogue', 'brushoff', 'budlet', 'cathepsin', 'centesimi', 'chaste', 'chicayote', 'coastal', 'coppice', 'couple', 'cuapinole', 'cytoplasm', 'daubingly', 'dearth', 'deasil', 'drightin', 'drudge', 'ejecta', 'feelable', 'fistnote', 'flareback', 'folial', 'fortunate', 'garrulous', 'gemmology', 'glaringly', 'gleet', 'globule', 'gluepot', 'googol', 'googul', 'humuslike', 'ichnology', 'illiberal', 'issite', 'karyotin', 'kella', 'ketol', 'knowingly', 'lysogenic', 'macaque', 'meddle', 'menseful', 'mocha', 'mournival', 'musher', 'natty', 'nonactive', 'nonserous', 'outcut', 'outspeak', 'overheavy', 'partially', 'pernor', 'picnic', 'prickwood', 'pyorrheal', 'redly', 'refine', 'regaler', 'rollick', 'sandling', 'sarcastic', 'scypha', 'severely', 'sinkage', 'sissyish', 'sogging', 'staling', 'steellike', 'stonelike', 'stoneware', 'tadpolism', 'tarditude', 'tazia', 'thymiosis', 'tightener', 'tritical', 'trundler', 'undenuded', 'underbank', 'unpaining', 'untraded', 'wayfare', 'woodworm', 'woofer', 'zemeism'];

  // Stores the count of the remaining words
  dictionary.wordCount = dictionary.words.length;

  /*
  *  Returns a random letter from dictionary.letters
  */
  dictionary.randLetter = function () {
    return this.letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 % 26)];
  };

  /*
  *  Replaces one letter of a word with a randomly selected letter
  */
  dictionary.replaceLetter = function (word) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 % word.length);
    var newWord = word.slice(0, index) + word.slice(index + 1);
    return newWord += this.randLetter();
  };

  /*
  *  Returns a random word from dictionary.words
  */
  dictionary.randWord = function () {
    return this.words[Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 % this.wordCount)];
  };

  /*
  *  Randomly shuffles the letters around in a word
  */
  dictionary.shuffle = function (word) {
    var fragments = word.split('');
    for (var i = fragments.length; i > 0;) {
      var random = parseInt(Math.random() * i);
      var temp = fragments[--i];
      fragments[i] = fragments[random];
      fragments[random] = temp;
    }
    return fragments.join('');
  };

  /*
  *  Returns the correct answer for the current word
  */
  dictionary.getCorrectChoice = function (word) {
    return this.shuffle(word);
  };

  /*
  *  Returns an incorrect answer for the current word
  */
  dictionary.getIncorrectChoice = function (word) {
    word = this.replaceLetter(word);
    return this.shuffle(word);
  };

  /*
  *  Randomly assigns the current word and correct and incorrect choices to the four buttons
  */
  function assignWords() {
  // Clear the timeout for the previous question
  window.clearTimeout(dictionary.timeout);

  // Allow 5 seconds for the user to get the right answer
  dictionary.timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
    alert('you lose!');
  }, 5000);

  var currWord = document.getElementById('currentWord');
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

  // Randomly choose a word to use as the anagram test
  currWord.innerHTML = dictionary.randWord();

  // Randomly choose a button to hold the correct choice
  dictionary.correctButton = buttons[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
  dictionary.correctButton.innerHTML = dictionary.getCorrectChoice(currWord.innerHTML);

  // Give the rest of the buttons incorrect choices
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (buttons[i] === dictionary.correctButton) {
      continue;
    } else {
      buttons[i].innerHTML = dictionary.getIncorrectChoice(currWord.innerHTML);
    }
  }
}

  // View object used to change information displayed on the page
  var view = {};

  // Stores the player's current score
  view.score = 0;

  // The timer that has the remaining time to answer the question
  view.timer = 0;

  // 
  view.resetData = function() {

  };

  view.displayData = function() {
    assignWords();
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (event.target === dictionary.correctButton) {
          assignWords();
        }
      });
    }
  };

  view.displayData();

})();
```

Comment: I've updated my description to show my current code, I thought it would be better to leave it out because it isn't really relevant. It currently just uses a setTimeout set for 5 seconds, but that doesn't really help with displaying the time left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setInterval with a small interval such as 50ms to update your timer display.

To get the time left, instead of decrementing a counter by 1 every second, just note the start time and subtract it from the current time. This will give you the total elapsed milliseconds since the timer started which you can then format for display.

Answer (score -1):

Have found similar code on the W3C website and thought it might be what you are looking for:

```
        var d = new Date();
        var x = document.getElementById("demo");
        var h = d.getHours();
        var m = d.getMinutes();
        var s = d.getSeconds();
        var ms = d.getMilliseconds();
        x.innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + ":" + ms;
```

Comment: `addZero()` is defined where, exactly?